# Wordpress constantly running out of memory

Tags: htaccess, wp-config, memory

My Wordpress installation on a shared hoster is constantly running out of memory:

The error pops up at seemingly random, for example when uploading photos or sometimes without doing anything just browsing the Admin area.

It is a very fresh installation (with little content and traffic), I receive this error no matter which Theme and which plugins I use.

I already added these lines to my config:

.htaccess

```
php_value memory_limit 128M
```

wp_config.php

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M');
define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
```

My PHP Limit seems sufficient:

PHP Memory Limit:

```
memory_limit    512M    512M
```

HOWEVER after all this my memory monitor plugin still says:

```
WordPress Memory Limit: 40M
```

Do I have to do anything else to apply these changes?

Comment: have you asked your host?

Comment: About what? I asked them if I might have too few memory but they told me it's 512MB and it seems true according to the phpinfo output. The problem seems to be that the WordPress Memory Limit doesn't react to config changes (it's still 40MB despite me changing it everywhere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`memory_limit = 128M`

in php.ini. Your syntax may be wrong.

You can run a function called phpinfo to see what kind of memory allocation you really have. Make a plain text file and call it `phpinfo.php` and put just this line in it:

`<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

then put the file in the root of your server, and then go to that file with your web browser, i.e. mydomain.com/phpinfo.php

You'l see all the php info you need; scroll down for memory settings. If you get an error, that means your web hosting company won't allow phpinfo to run for security reasons.

But that will tell you what the real memory settings are and if your host is being honest. If they are, ask them how to bump memory for your account. If you only see a memory limit of 40 megs, than you're not able to change it due to their restrictions.

Comment: As mentioned in my question, I really do have 512MB PHP memory limit. Still, wordpress memory limit is 40MB.

Comment: Where/how do you see 512MB?

Comment: in my phpinfo.php

Comment: memory_limit 512M 512M

Comment: On top of that I have a plugin telling me:
WP Memory Limit: 40M
PHP Memory Limit: 512M

Comment: I edited the code directly by changing the default value and now I can use the full 512MB. I don't see how my wp-config syntax was wrong, but for now I'll leave it at that, although the next update will probably break my change.

Comment: Ok so I was able to set the WP memory limit in wp-config and had the changes applied properly. Turns out that I put the setting too far at the bottom of the file. I am still running out of memory when uploading a photo though, specifically at the crunching process, no matter how much memory I assign.